# How to change background color of Nice Menus parent item

Tags: navigation

After trying everything I could find via FireBug, I still can't find a way to change the CSS for the background color of a horizontal menu set which uses the Nice Menus module. The menu is inside a custom region with a custom background color, but always picks up the overall page background color. It acts as if it's a window to the page background, and changing the page background in theme settings will change its color.  The theme being used is MAYO. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Just to double-check, you are clearing the theme cache every time you update the CSS, right?

Comment: I've done that but probably not every time I tried a change. I think I just haven't been able to identify the right css selector. In Firebug if I could find where the color is being specified, I should be able to change it real-time (temporarily), right?

Comment: Ok then. Yes, you should be able to change it in real time with Firebug.

Comment: Using Firebug and other similar utilities, I have not been able to locate anything that already has a background-color property I could change and see any difference, nor any other declarations I could add the background property to, successfully. It seems that color property is being controlled from somewhere other than Nice Menus' style css or colors css, but it remains a mystery.

Comment: Do a search of your css files for !important. That should be your culprit. I just grabbed Mayo and Nice menus and could change the background color on ul.nice-menu li a so there's either an !important on there somewhere or an #ID for that region trumping the background color